# displacement of cosinor waves (circadian activity) R

Tags: r, regression, time-series, nonlinear-regression, cosinor

I have circadian activity data. I have managed to fit cosinor waves thanks to all the help from this post [Fitting sine wave with lm in R for circadian activity- frequencies?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/557475/fitting-sine-wave-with-lm-in-r-for-circadian-activity-frequencies?noredirect=1#comment1027573_557475)

The data is % time spent performing a certain behaviour for each hour across a 48 hour period for 28 individuals. Cosinor analysis is the standard method of circadian activity analysis, however my data is more complicated than current r packages allow for.

I have two treatments and two sex's. I need to see if the **amplitude** and the **acrophase** are altered by the four conditions, and the **interactions** (sex*treatment). The standardised way of doing this is with the cosinor package. This does not allow complex datasets (with interactions, and with repeated 24 hours) to be modelled. Only factors with no more than two levels can be included. A new package has been released (cosinoRmixedeffects) however the package and examples provided are not reproducible.

How can I investigate the differences in amplitude and acrophase statistically? Thank you so much!!

I can graph the activity waves as follows;

```
new<- data[ which(data$treatment== 'a'),]  

b<- data[ which(data$treatment== 'b'),]  

lmfit <- lm(walking ~ sin(2*pi/24*zt) + cos(2*pi/24*zt), data=b) 
pframe <- data.frame(zt=seq(min(b$zt),max(b$zt),length=612))
pframe$walking <- predict(lmfit,newdata=pframe)

lmfit2 <- lm(walking ~ sin(2*pi/24*zt) + cos(2*pi/24*zt), data=new)
pframe2 <- data.frame(zt=seq(min(new$zt),max(new$zt),length=526))
pframe2$walking <- predict(lmfit2,newdata=pframe2)


ggplot(data,aes(x=zt,y=walking, col=treatment))+ #, group = treatment ))+
  geom_point(alpha=0.2, size = 1)+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "black"), labels=c("A", "B"))+
  labs(color='Condition') +
  geom_line(data=pframe,colour="red")+
  ylab("% time spent walking")+
  geom_line(data=pframe2, colour="black")+
  scale_x_continuous("Zeitgeber Time", breaks=seq(0,48,6) , label= c("0", "6", "12", "18", "24", "6","12", "18", "24"))+
  cleanup
```

[image]

Example data;

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   1138 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ treatment: chr  "b" "b" "b" "b" ...
 $ sex      : chr  "F" "M" "M" "F" ...
 $ zt       : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ walking  : num  2.333 16 0.833 1.833 4.333 ...

 dput(data)
structure(list(treatment = c("b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", 
"a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", 
"b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", 
"b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", 
"a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", 
"a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", 
"a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", 
"a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"
), sex = c("F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", 
"M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", 
"M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", 
"M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", 
"M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", 
"M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", 
"F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M"), zt = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 
39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 
39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 
45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 
46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L
), walking = c(2.333333333, 16, 0.833333333, 1.833333333, 4.333333333, 
8.833333333, 6.666666667, 6.166666667, 0.666666667, 3.5, 1.666666667, 
0, 0, 0.333333333, 0, 1.833333333, 2, 0.333333333, 3.333333333, 
6.833333333, 3.833333333, 1.333333333, 0.333333333, 0.666666667, 
0, 3.333333333, 2.5, 3.833333333, 2.5, 10, 0.333333333, 1.333333333, 
0, 0.833333333, 2.166666667, 0.333333333, 0, 0, 1.5, 2.333333333, 
4.666666667, 4.833333333, 0, 3, 0.333333333, 0, 1.5, 0.5, 1.333333333, 
1.5, 4.833333333, 0.666666667, 7.833333333, 3.666666667, 5.833333333, 
5.833333333, 8, 1.166666667, 4.666666667, 2, 5, 6.166666667, 
1.166666667, 0.5, 9.666666667, 12.5, 13.5, 16.16666667, 3, 0.5, 
1.333333333, 2.833333333, 4.5, 1.333333333, 5, 3, 1.5, 2.5, 0, 
0.666666667, 0, 4, 3.333333333, 1.666666667, 9, 3.833333333, 
4.833333333, 2, 1.833333333, 4, 0, 0.666666667, 2, 0, 0, 2.166666667, 
0.666666667, 0.5, 3.166666667, 5.666666667, 4.5, 2.666666667, 
0, 0.666666667, 0.333333333, 1.5, 0, 1, 3.5, 1.5, 0.833333333, 
1.166666667, 11.16666667, 4.666666667, 4.666666667, 2.333333333, 
2.5, 1.333333333, 4.166666667, 1.833333333, 1.333333333, 9.833333333, 
0.666666667, 2.166666667, 0, 2.333333333, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0, 
3, 5.5, 1, 6.166666667, 0.5, 0.666666667, 0.166666667, 2.166666667, 
0.5, 0.666666667, 1.666666667, 14.66666667, 5.666666667, 4.5, 
7, 1.166666667, 9.5, 1.166666667, 1.5, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1.5, 3, 0.833333333, 
0, 1.333333333, 0, 0, 1.5, 3.333333333, 15.33333333, 4.166666667, 
0, 0, 0.833333333, 0, 0, 0.833333333, 7.666666667, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 
3, 7.5, 5, 3.166666667, 3.833333333, 2.5, 5.666666667, 2.833333333, 
2, 1.333333333, 7.166666667, 1.5, 4, 5, 10.33333333, 2.5, 1, 
0, 6.833333333, 11, 2, 15.5, 6.833333333, 5.166666667, 4.333333333, 
2.333333333, 7.666666667, 1.833333333, 2.5, 1, 7.666666667, 7.833333333, 
2.666666667, 2.5, 5.5, 2.5, 7.5, 2.5, 1.333333333, 5.333333333, 
4.666666667, 6.166666667, 3, 4.333333333, 4.666666667, 0.833333333, 
3.5, 2.166666667, 6.333333333, 12.33333333, 4.333333333, 1.333333333, 
5.166666667, 2.333333333, 2, 1.833333333, 1.166666667, 0, 1.5, 
4.166666667, 2.333333333, 1, 1.666666667, 0.333333333, 1.833333333, 
3, 1.5, 2.666666667, 0.333333333, 1.166666667, 0.833333333, 1.5, 
2.166666667, 2.666666667, 3, 1, 1.333333333, 0.5, 1.5, 0.666666667, 
0.333333333, 3.166666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.833333333, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 
0.166666667, 0, 0.333333333, 0.166666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0.333333333, 0, 0.166666667, 
0.333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 0.166666667, 
0.5, 0.333333333, 0.166666667, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 0.666666667, 1, 0, 0, 1.5, 0, 0, 1.166666667, 
0, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.166666667, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.833333333, 0.666666667, 0.666666667, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.666666667, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 1.833333333, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.166666667, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666666667, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0, 0.166666667, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666666667, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.333333333, 0.333333333, 0, 0.333333333, 0.166666667, 
0, 0.666666667, 1, 0.166666667, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9.166666667, 7.166666667, 
18.16666667, 1.333333333, 0.333333333, 1.5, 2.5, 2.333333333, 
0.666666667, 0.166666667, 1, 0, 0, 4, 4.5, 3.833333333, 2.833333333, 
3, 9.666666667, 1.333333333, 1.166666667, 2, 1.333333333, 4.333333333, 
10.33333333, 4.5, 5.5, 1.333333333, 4, 2.666666667, 1.333333333, 
1.666666667, 1.833333333, 3.5, 6, 4.333333333, 8.5, 3.833333333, 
0, 3.166666667, 1.333333333, 2, 0, 0, 1.833333333, 10.16666667, 
5.333333333, 2, 2.166666667, 3.5, 0.166666667, 2.166666667, 0, 
0, 0, 1.666666667, 0, 1.833333333, 2, 3.5, 0.666666667, 1.833333333, 
0, 0.333333333, 0, 2, 4.333333333, 1.166666667, 2.666666667, 
4.166666667, 3.666666667, 8.666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.5, 7.166666667, 
2.5, 2.166666667, 1.333333333, 0.5, 2.333333333, 6.333333333, 
9.833333333, 2.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.333333333, 1, 0, 0.166666667, 0.5, 
0, 1.666666667, 1.166666667, 0.666666667, 0, 7.833333333, 3.666666667, 
6.666666667, 6.166666667, 6.166666667, 6.666666667, 1.5, 3.166666667, 
8.666666667, 0, 0.666666667, 6.5, 2.833333333, 4.833333333, 4.833333333, 
6.833333333, 2.333333333, 13, 1.166666667, 5, 2.5, 2.333333333, 
0.833333333, 2.833333333, 1.333333333, 0.5, 0.333333333, 5.666666667, 
5.5, 2.5, 0.333333333, 4.833333333, 2, 1, 0.833333333, 0, 0, 
4.5, 0.333333333, 2.5, 1.333333333, 4.333333333, 3.666666667, 
4.166666667, 3.833333333, 4.833333333, 2, 2.833333333, 2.166666667, 
1.5, 1.666666667, 4.333333333, 2.166666667, 5.333333333, 2.333333333, 
0, 1.5, 1.833333333, 0.5, 5.666666667, 5.666666667, 8.5, 0, 0.666666667, 
0, 0, 12.16666667, 9.833333333, 3.666666667, 3.333333333, 1.166666667, 
1.166666667, 0, 1.833333333, 2.333333333, 0, 0, 1.833333333, 
3.578154426, 1.166666667, 2.833333333, 6, 0.166666667, 2.833333333, 
1.166666667, 6.666666667, 1.833333333, 1.166666667, 0.833333333, 
6.666666667, 1.833333333, 8.833333333, 11.5, 4.833333333, 5, 
1, 4.5, 1.833333333, 1.333333333, 12.16666667, 2.5, 3.5, 6.338028169, 
2.666666667, 1.833333333, 10, 3, 3.5, 5.166666667, 3.166666667, 
3.666666667, 1.166666667, 3.833333333, 2.5, 5.5, 4.166666667, 
5.833333333, 16.83333333, 2.833333333, 5.833333333, 5.166666667, 
3.666666667, 0, 0, 4.5, 7.291666667, 15.625, 14.16666667, 1.458333333, 
1.909722222, 2.256944444, 2.430555556, 1.215277778, 2, 5.666666667, 
0.666666667, 3.5, 2.833333333, 2.166666667, 8.166666667, 2.602230483, 
6.319702602, 1.672862454, 4.089219331, 2.941176471, 2.573529412, 
6.25, 0, 1.166666667, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0.666666667, 0.166666667, 
0.833333333, 0.333333333, 0, 0.166666667, 0, 0.666666667, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0.5, 1, 0.166666667, 0.166666667, 0.166666667, 
0, 0, 0.166666667, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.333333333, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 0.166666667, 0.333333333, 0, 0.166666667, 
0.166666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 0, 0.666666667, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.166666667, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0.333333333, 
0.666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0.166666667, 1.166666667, 
0.666666667, 0, 0.166666667, 0.333333333, 0.833333333, 0, 0.333333333, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.666666667, 2.666666667, 5.5, 1.5, 2.333333333, 
2.833333333, 2.166666667, 1.833333333, 3, 6.5, 4, 6.166666667, 
18.33333333, 5.833333333, 1.5, 4.5, 4.5, 5.833333333, 0.666666667, 
0.333333333)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1138L
))
```

Comment: (1) The restrictions you say are imposed by the package are strangely arbitrary - in any case defining a dichotomous predictor for three of your four conditions should fool it. (2) A sinusoidal model doesn't look like a very good fit,  from looking at your graph. Presumably the creatures, whatever they are, stop eating when they're asleep.

Comment: In your previous threads we have already discussed why your model is inappropriate.  Adopting a suitable model would likely automatically resolve the problems that are particular to this one.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica thanks! Good thinking but unfortunately I've already tried to code the factors too fool it, however as it only recognises binary input (e.g control or not control ect.) this doesn't allow for interactions  which is a pain.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I had a look at the GAMS, however for all the circadian literature a cosinor model is used so I am hesitant to step away from this!

Comment: That puts us in a bind, because you are basically asking "how do I use the wrong tool to investigate my data?"  There is no good answer.